# How can I avoid duplicate primary keys in SQL import?

Tags: sql, import

I have two sites I'm trying to merge. Site 1 has 1500 products in a custom post type, with associated meta and an attached featured image. Site 2 has 250 products in the exact same custom post type, but with a different category.

I exported the five tables I believe contain all of the appropriate information from Site 2. When I import this into Site 1 I get this error:

```
Duplicate entry '8434' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

How can I insert this data into Site 1 without overwriting any existing products?

Comment: This question is probably better served on [Data Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) or [Stack overflow proper](http://stackoveflow.com) since it doesn't have anything to do WordPress specifically and is more about database merging.  Personally, I'd import the larger database to your new site, and then write a script to parse through the smaller database and insert the records programmatically.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but I feel like WordPress has enough unique structure in the way they handle content (file vs. database) that it is still WordPress-specific.

Comment: WordPress-specific solutions I have tried:

1 - WP Migrate DB Pro - this overwrote the tables
2 - Default WordPress export/import plugin - data was added appropriately, but no media files migrated. 
3 - SQL export/import - got the error listed above in my original question

Comment: Well, any database or app is going to have a "unique" structure.  I don't think you're going to find a plugin that's going to do this for you, I'm afraid you're going to have get your hands dirty and write some code.

Comment: I somehow managed to get this to work. I wish I could provide more detail, but I suspect that the WordPress import function worked for all the data, and then WordPress took its normal sweet time in importing the media. Eventually it was all there...